# Is fleeing from battle considered "acting under attack"?

Tags: movement, numenera, cypher-system

A short movement isn't enough to flee from battle, since the opponent can do a short movement *and* an attack: "A character can also try to make a short
move and take another (relatively simple) physical action, like make an attack" (p. 208)

So to completely flee from combat a long movement is required.

Page 227 of Cypher-system states that anything but moving grant an immediate extra attack from the opponent. But it is also specified that the character "is assumed to be moving slowly and carefully out of the fight".

While this is surely true for a short movement, is this also valid for a long movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That rule is talking about both short and long movements

As *adjusting your position* (moving an immediate distance) take no action (pg.208):

> As a part of another action, a character can
>   adjust his position—stepping back a few
>   feet while using an ability, sliding over in
>   combat to take on a different opponent to
>   help his friend, pushing through a door he
>   just opened, and so on. This is considered
>   an **immediate distance**, and a character can
>   move this far **as part of another action**.

While both short and long moves take an action, short actions being difficult 0 Speed tasks:

> In a round, as an action, a character
>   can make a short move. In this case, he
>   is doing nothing but moving up to about
>   50 feet (15 m). Some terrain or situations
>   will change the distance a character can
>   move, but generally, making a short move
>   is considered to be a **difficulty 0 action**. No
>   roll is needed; he just gets where he’s going
>   **as his action**.

While a long move is also an action, but a difficult 4 Speed task:

> A character can try to make a long
>   move—up to 100 feet (30 m) or so—in one
>   round. This is a **Speed task with a difficulty
>   of 4**. As with any action, he can use skills,
>   assets, or Effort to decrease the difficulty.
>   Terrain, obstacles, or other circumstances
>   can increase the difficulty. A successful roll
>   means the character moved the distance
>   safely. Failure means that at some point
>   during the move, he stops or stumbles (the
>   GM determines where this happens).

Finally, if you also make a Speed 4 check, you may take both a short move *and* an action:

> A character can also try to make a s**hort
>   move** and take another (relatively simple)
>   **physical action**, like make an attack. As with
>   the attempt to make a long move, this is a
>   **Speed task with a difficulty of 4**, and failure
>   means that the character stops at some
>   point, slipping or stumbling or otherwise
>   getting held up.

So, as long as you don't use that last option and simply make a short or long movement, you should be safe against attackers. However, You may also make an attack *and* move away while also being safe, as you are permitted to fight while engaged without any risks of getting attacked, you simply must make a difficult 4 Speed check before you can do that.

Comment: The part stating that the character "is assumed to be moving **slowly and carefully** out of the fight" seems to clash with the concept of the long move. While I'm definitely not a fan of opportunity attacks, fleeing from a battle like this seems too simply

Comment: Yes, but nothing prevents the enemies from using the same kind of movement to remain engaged.

Comment: Note that these "attacks of opportunity" didnt even exist in Numenera and that kind of thing still happened naturally. Don't let that mechanic bog your game down.

Comment: Replace "immediate extra attack from the opponent" (as stated in page 227) to "opportunity attack" if you prefer, but this rule is a matter of fact. Just wondering if this still apply to long movement, since it is stated that the movement should be slow and careful (and a long movement isn't). Beside from this rule, just want to know if a PC or NPC can safely run away from combat. Players can become frustrated if enemies start to safely flee when hurt. Note: sorry if this message could sound harsh, english is not my natural language.

Comment: "Slowly and carefully" is only a flavorful description because you dont just dance out, or turn your back and run away, that would make you distracted enough for them to attack you. The example given in the book is "operating a door mechanism", which is an action that would trigger this attack.

Comment: I'm very sorry to appear stubborn, but itn't moving a long distance (action that require a roll) considered running? Doesn't it implies to turn your back to the opponent?

Comment: It doesnt say anywhere that you do.